# How do I manipulate the grids and axis with ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataset consisting `Date, maximum value, minimum value` and the `average.` 
I want to plot the `average` value against the Date. 
I am using `ggplot2` for this purpose. 
This is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(Date, Avg)) + 
  geom_point()
```

The plot from this code is showing several x-axis grid lines. It is plotting gridlines one for each day. But, this is not what I want.

I want to plot one grid line for one month. Lets say, the first grid line for 1st Jan, ... 12th grid for 1st Dec.

However, I am aware of assigning a new column consisting of dates, by using the following command:

```
seq(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by=1)
```

but I want to manipulate the number of grids as per my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `+ scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month")` ?

Comment: Thanks @scoa it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set ticks intervals on an axis with dates values with the option `breaks` in `scale_x_datetime` / `scale_y_datetime`. Here:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(Date, Avg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month")
```